# validates in rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, validation, model

I have a model with valid data; everything works.

In the form, I select as how to select the option I choose I want to be valid also 2 fields

```
validates_presence_of :is_ranking, :on => :update
validates :awards_count, :on => :update, :unless => :is_ranking == 1
```

Now as is_ranking == 1 to check again: awards_count
All sent from a form before being added to the database

How do I force rails to valid these two additional fields on the form I choose to rip options in select?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you should [use symbol or string](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_validations_callbacks.html#using-a-symbol-with-if-and-unless) with `:if` and `:unless`

Try to replace condition with method

```
validates :awards_count, :on => :update, :unless => :is_ranking?

# You actually don't need that method in case your `is_ranking` field is `boolean`.
def is_ranking?
  is_ranking == 1
end
```

Or with string

```
validates :awards_count, :on => :update, :unless => "is_ranking?"
```

Comment: i have 

    validates_presence_of :awards_count, :on => :update, :unless => :is_ranking?
  
    def is_ranking?
     is_ranking == '1'
    end

but it does not work all the time trying to valid. Although is_ranking == 2